# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am creating an app in which one module allows to scan the Qrcode and the other generates the QRcode.

To generate QRcode i am using this library:

```
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.1.0'
```

To Scan a QR code i am using this library :

```
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
```

both library are using ZXING , that is why i am using this multiple dex error in Android Studio.

Please help so that i can include both libraries in my gradle. I know can solve this using "exclude" , but i don't know which class from both libraries are clashing.

Comment: **public class MyApplication extends Application** this type of class in your project

Comment: @nandkishormewara I don't have that kind of class in my project.

Answer (score 4):

For me this was caused by having duplicate dependencies in my project.

Turns out I had included zxing dependency by different means and different versions in my project.

One of them was from Facebook SDK which used the latest version and another one was already included via a `.jar` file in the `/libs` directory and was an ancient version.

To resolve the issue I removed the Facebook SDK, found the old version and instead of including the jar directly I replaced it with:

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.1'
```

in my app's `build.gradle`.

After that included Facebook SDK, clean/rebuild with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

You need to Enable **Multidex** please check Highlighted part of image

[image]

Comment: I did that got this kind of error for multidex

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

I was using other library which used same core ZXing library to generate the QRcode in to a bitmap.

What i did instead :

```
    com.google.zxing.Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();
// String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");
int width = 250;
int height = 250;
BitMatrix bm = writer
        .encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
        Config.ARGB_8888);

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {// width
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {// height
        ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK
                : Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

used com.google.zxing.writer to generate bitmap and set it to my imageview.

Thanks @pranavjoshi

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the Zxing library from one of the conflicting dependencies, like this example:

```
  implementation ('com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.5.0') {exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'}
```